# How do I find the sum of squares of my predicting variables with statsmodels linear model OLS?

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

I have a relatively small dataset consisting of x, y coordinates and organic matter content. I perform a simple multi-linear regression in Python using statsmodels.api ordinary least square (OLS) with organic matter content being the dependent variable and the others predictors. Firstly, I find the total sum of squares of my model (called mreg) with the built-in method 'mreg.centered_tss'. Now I have to find the sum of squares for my predictors, the x and y variable. Is it possible to do with the statsmodels.api or should I use a for loop instead?

I have used the .ess and the .centered_tss to determine the sum of squares of the model. I only need to know the sum of squares of my modelled variables x and y coordinates compared to the mean.

edit: I think what I am asking for is the residual sum of squares of my x coordinates and y coordinates from the model.

Thomas

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, The explained sum of squares is in `ess` attribute https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.ess.html

Comment: Hi Josef.
Thank you, I know the .ess and .centered_tss which are the sum of squares for the model in general. However, I need the sum of squares of the variables I modelled, hence, the x and y coordinates.

Comment: I have no idea what "sum of squares of explanatory variables" means. Maybe you want anova, `anova_lm` in statsmodels with results of OLS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there should be a .ssr method for the regression sum of squares